# how to loop csv and write into new xlsx

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
import csv

filename = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\data.csv"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0] 


filename1 = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\template.xlsm"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1, keep_vba=True) 
ws2 = wb2.active 

mr = ws1.max_row 
mc = ws1.max_column 


for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
    for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
        c = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = j) 
        ws2.cell(row = i+2, column = j).value = c.value 


wb2.save(filename1)
```

As openpyxl does not support .csv file format, i have no idea how to replace "ws1", i try to use panda to handle the job, but dataframe cannot .cell, please help and thank you

Comment: can you clarify this bit: 'i try to use panda to handle the job, but dataframe cannot .cell, please help and thank you'?

Comment: panda convent csv to dataFrame, c = df.cell <<< fail, but if ok, it will be the most lazy way i thank XD